# Accessing Spring beans in custom JSP tags

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tags, custom-tags

I'm attempting to use Spring service classes I've created inside custom JSP tags. For example given a  conditional style tag, which will call a relationship service and then display the appropriate content.

I know you can access a spring bean in the custom JSP Java code via `WebApplicationContextUtils`, but this doesn't seem clean to me and I can see a problem with this if that service you call has other `Autowired` services, exceptions will occur.

I've read comments that this is accessing legacy code (JSP tags) with Spring, that you shouldn't access services in a tag as it breaks the MVC model.. what's the best way to be doing this? Should I create service classes specifically for use by the custom tags?

Comment: Spring MVC controller( C)  allows you to set model (M) to be used in JSP page (V). Check here for an example : http://www.javapedia.net/Spring-MVC-Interview-questions#qanda862

Comment: @javapedia.net I want to use a reusable tag... otherwise I have to set that object for every view.